How can you prevent forked child processes from disconnecting DBD::Pg connections, when you have no access to $dbh?
I have a library that needs to fork() to fire-and-forget some code. However when the child process spawned by fork() is destroyed, the DBD::Pg's END is called and inadvertently kills the parents connection. On-top of this, the code has no access to the $dbh, and can't use DBI.
Here is some code that reproduces the issue:
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=foo', '', '');

if (!fork()) {
  CORE::say 'In child, doing stuff!';
  exit 0;
}

sleep 2; # Provide adequate time for the child to be reaped.


my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q[select NOW();]);
$sth->execute(); # Error! Something, something, connection terminated!
my $time = $sth->fetch->[0];
CORE::say "It is $time o'clock";

Here is the error:
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally


You might look into DBIx::Connector or DBIx::Handler

@Shawn Those don't really help my scenario where I have no idea if the program using the library uses DBI or not. But I do agree, those modules solve this problem if you have access to the $dbh, though you'd be re-connecting per-fork which is not ideal.

Instead of using exit, you can use POSIX::_exit, this causes END's to not be evaluated when the child exits.
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=foo', '', '');

if (!fork()) {
  CORE::say 'In child, doing stuff!';
  POSIX::_exit(0);
}

sleep 2; # Provide adequate time for the child to be reaped.

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q[select NOW();]);
$sth->execute(); # Error! Something, something, connection terminated!
my $time = $sth->fetch->[0];
CORE::say "It is $time o'clock";

